# When using a convert char to ASCII value routine, need to find out what values it is actually returning as they are not strictly ascii

Tags: ascii, ucs2

When testing my code that uses a routine that checks for chars to show using an ASCII value routine, my program should drop control chars but keep chars that may be entered by the user. It seems that while the ASCII value routine is called "ascii", it does not just return ascii values: giving it a char of ƒ returns 402.

For example have found [this web site](https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp852.html#standard_character_set)
 but it doesn't have ƒ  402  that I can see.

Need to know whether there are other ascii codes above 402 that I need to test my code with. The character set used internally by the software that 'ascii' is written in uses UCS2. The web site found doesn't mention USC2.

Comment: There are only 128 ASCII characters (including 0). Consider which encoding/character set you actually want to use and rephrase your question.

Comment: @escitalopram thanks for the comment, documentation says "character set used internally by the engine in memory is UCS2" - does this answer you question about encoding/character set?

Comment: 402 is not an ASCII code. As @escitalopram has already said, there are only 128 ASCII codes (from 0 to 127). Extended ASCII would increase this to 256, which makes the maximum extended ASCII value 255.

Comment: USC-2 is a character encoding for a subset of Unicode. But you should probably consider the whole set because UTF-16 is a "drop-in" replacement for USC-2 that is transparent to many programs. See [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/12.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt) for a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many interpretations ouf »Control Character« out there, but I'll assume you mean [C0 and C1 control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) (includes references to the relevant Unicode Standards).

The commonly used 32-bit integer representation of Unicode characters in general is the codepoint notation: »U+« followed by a at least 4 digit positive hex number, which you will find near mentions of characters, e.g. as in »U+007F (delete)«. The result of your »ASCII value« routine will probably be this number without the »U+«;

UCS-2 is a specific encoding for Unicode characters, which you probably won't need to care about directly), and is equivalent to Unicode codepoints for all characters within the the range of the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) only.

Comment: thanks again @escitalopram, having scanned the link you included, I'm happy with the routine being tested excludes control characters (ascii < 32), just worried if there are chars represented by 'ascii???' codes greater than 402 I'm excluding them as control chars, will do some more research. I'm wondering if the code just needs to check ascii < 32 to remove control chars.